# Can we call two contracts in web3.eth.filter method?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, events, web3-providers

I have two contract address and I want to check events on both in one call.
I mean, can we pass two contract address in one option param like i do below?

```
let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(web3Provider);
let options = {
  fromBlock:'latest',
  toBlock: 'latest',
  address: ADDRESS1,Address2
};
let filter = web3.eth.filter(options);
filter.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Or there is any way to combine all events from both contract?

Answer (score 1):

This would only work if the events have the same signature (event name and arguments) or none ( [] ).
You pass in an array of the addresses you want to scan.

```
let options = {
  fromBlock:'latest',
  toBlock: 'latest',
  address: [ADDRESS1,Address2],
  topics: []
};
```